# Should there be a cap next to my furnace ac drain?

Tags: repair, air-conditioning, furnace, cooling, blower

In the picture below, the left side has a good amount of airflow while the ac/blower is running. The tube on the right is the drain that the condensation flows out of to the floor. Should there be a cap on the left opening? Seems odd as there is so much air coming out of there.  [image: ac]

Comment: What's the make/model?  What does the user manual say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should be either plugged, or plumbed as a secondary drain. A 3/4" MNPT plug should do the trick.

[image: 3/4" MNPT plug]